# Generate a files list and truncate it in 2 list of X Mb of files each

Tags: find, grep, awk

I need to generate a list of all files in a certain dir, and truncate it in X lists containing each one a fixed amount of data of files.

E.g.
I have 95 Gb of data.

- generate the file list (`total.txt`)
- split `total.txt` in 3 lists:

  1. `slice1.txt` containing the list of the 1st 35 Gb of files
  2. `slice2.txt` containing the list of the following 35 Gb of files
  3. `slice3.txt` containing the list of the remaining files

Any hint? I've googled and played around with find, awk, grep, but this task seems really above my competencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) command to separate your files:

```
split total.txt -b 4444160
```

The above would split `total.txt` into 35 GB files.

Comment: total.txt is just a list of all files, like ls. Definitely wants `split` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read filename; do cat $filename; done < total.txt | split -b 35G - slice
```

This will create "sliceaa", "sliceab", "sliceac" which you can rename.

With other implementation of [`split`](http://man.cx/split#top), you may have to say `-b 35000m`

If you have bash, you can write

```
cat $(< total.txt) | split -b 35G - slice
```

assume there are not hundreds or thousands of filenames.

To create `total.txt`

```
files=(*)
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}" > total.txt
```

Comment: `fradeve@edgar:~$ while read filename; do cat $filename; done < total.txt | split -b 35G - slice`
`bash: total.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: @fradeve, updated

Comment: it works, but the file `sliceaa` contains the files themselves, not a list of them :) it's a bit-per-bit pasting of all files that are in one dir into a unique single file, not so useful if you want to generate a list of files :)

Comment: I guess your question wasn't clear enough. Anyway, loop over the files in total.txt (`while read filename; do ... done < total.txt`). Use [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat) to get the file size and keep a running total size ([bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)) and a list of filenames. If the running size exceeds your limit, print the list of files to the current slice file.